# Rotate animation for feather icon cause a weird wiggling stroke on icon

Tags: react-native, animation, svg-animate, react-native-reanimated

I have a gear icon which I import from react native feather icons and I wrap a Animated View on it so I can rotate it infinitely with react native reanimated 3.

the problem is when it rotate the icon stroke is not remain straight and smooth and getting a wiggling effect. how can I solve this problem?

[image]

and this is the code which handles the rotation:

```js
import {Settings} from 'react-native-feather';

const rotationDeg = useSharedValue(0);

  const rotation = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [{rotateZ: `${rotationDeg.value}deg`}],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rotationDeg.value === 0) {
      rotationDeg.value = withRepeat(
        withTiming(360, {
          duration: 2000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
        }),
        -1,
      );
    }
  }, [rotationDeg]);

return (
  <Animated.View style={[rotation]}>
     <Settings stroke="#646464" strokeWidth={1} width={25} height={25} />
  </Animated.View>
)
```

Comment: Does this only occur on react-native-reanimated 3 ?
I have created an sample here https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/rotation-gear-none-wiggling